# kernel time spent using openMPI?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, kernel, openmpi

I'm doing some investigation in profiling scalability tests on openMPI, with Linux Ubuntu 18.04.
I could profile the benchmark within some useful MPI profiling tools like mpiP, Scalasca, etc. However, still, there is an open question for me,

What is the kernel usage (time, memory, I/O, etc) to do an MPI job? I need to see kernel movements to profile the MPI tasks (processes) over different ranks, How can I profile the kernel usage? I think all the (mentioned above) profilers provide for me are from the user point of view, right?

Comment: `perf` on Linux might help you (you need privileged rights whatever the solution). Note that it is used by kernel developers as well as user-land developers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks, would you elaborate more? I tried with Perf somehow but in the end, I just could profile cache accesses, hit and miss rate. I need to more dig into kernel movements.

Comment: You can profile hardware events and draw call graphs. See https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html and https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial for more informations (the former talk about call graphs). Perf is quite low-level and hard to use, but this is an amazing tool, especially for kernel-related profiling. As for the rights, please read https://superuser.com/questions/980632/run-perf-without-root-rights. Note that the call graphs will not be precise due to sampling. If you need that, you may need a more intrusive method (eg. using kernel modules or a kernel build tweak).